# Usage of DISTINCT in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

Why my query is still showing the duplicate tuples?
I want all the attributes of all distinct tuples

```
select distinct * from employees;
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any duplicates with DISTINCT. You  probably THINK that there are duplicates but in fact there are not. For instance you could have invisible characters in your data (like space at the end of some strings, etc...). Nothing else we can do for you with what you have shown

Comment: distinct applies to all columns of your table. As that includes the primary key column, there won't be any duplicates by definition

Comment: Ok. Is NULL different from " " (i.e an empty string) ??

Comment: Provide sample data and the results that you want.  You probably don't understand what `select distinct` does.

Comment: *' Is NULL different from " " (i.e an empty string) ?'* Not in Oracle. This is controversial but it's the way it's been for more than thirty years and an awful lot of code would break if Oracle suddenly decided to treat NULL differently from an empty string.

Comment: Except what you showed isn't an empty string, it's a space; which do you really mean?

Comment: If the only difference between two rows in your `employees` table is a null (or blank space) in some column, then something has gone wrong. Do they have the same `employee_id` values? Sample data would really help here.

Comment: I meant "" i.e without any whitespace

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach related to *NULL values* and *empty strings* maybe the cause of the problem :

```
create table tab( id int, value varchar2(75));
insert into tab values(1,'  ');
insert into tab values(1,' ');
insert into tab values(1,'');
insert into tab values(1,null);

select distinct * from tab;
ID  VALUE
--  -----
1   
1   
1   (null)

select id, length(value) as value from tab;
ID  VALUE
--  -----
1   2   
1   1
1   (null)
1   (null)
```

Oracle considers `''` as `NULL` but the empty strings with ***length >= 1*** is not considered as `NULL`.

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca39c/1)

Comment: upvote for sql fidle (i didt know) and length>=1 precision

Answer (score 0):

If you need  all distinct results for a tuple then you should not use `*`  (all column) but explicitly select for only  the columns involved in tuple

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3 from employees;
```

Typically using all column selector  (`*`)  you select also the primary key from your table that typically (by definition)  is not duplicated  so using  `select * ...`
 you get all the rows  in table.

Answer (score 0):

If yours columns have some " " , you'll find duplicate because

Value1 value 2 " " is not
Value1 value 2 ""   nor 
value1 value2 NULL

Plus, PrimaryKey is always unique so 
select distinct *, is unique 
Often, if you need "select unique" in table employee, there a problem of conception because every employe should appears only once (if it is a real table employe without been linking)

Comment: Hi, I deleted my answer it was completly wrong.

Comment: I edited mine, because before your intervention i tought NULL <> '', in oracle NULL is also '' , you was right

Answer (score 0):

To fix this during import you would have to trim whitespace from the end of the string, this should take care of those 3 different characters. Note that LTRIM and RTRIM only removes "blanks" which further down in the documentation suggests that only spaces are considered. You would thus have to use a different trim function, like in the programming language you're using, to do this trimming.